# Inicio de seccion con net core 5 y usuario de SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-core-5.0

Buenas tengo una enorme duda, y es la siguiente e estado desarrollando una API en base a net core 5 y SQL Server 2016, ya tengo mas de un año con ella y tengo 3 aplicaciones ligadas.

El problema es que me están obligando a que inicie con diferentes usuarios. Actualmente tengo mi cadena de conexión.

```
    {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "WebApiDatabase": "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=dotnet-5-crud-api; User Id=testUser; Password=testPass123"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    }
}
```

Y funciona, no tengo ningún problema con esto, pero el problema surgió cuando pidieron que cada usuario se conectara con su propio usuario de SQL.

Pregunta, Esto es posible?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. ¿Es posible? Si. ¿Tiene sentido? Sólo si las aplicaciones tienen unos pocos usuarios contados con los dedos de la mano. ¿Quién se dedicará a administrar a esos usuarios? Quizá te convendría usar la [Autenticación de Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax), o incluso autenticación a través de [Active directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15)